# Fatal error: Class not found Laravel on routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm new on Laravel and currently messing around the Laravel's quickstart sample project. There're list of records on *tasks.blade.php*, then each record will have a link to view them at *tasksdetails.blade.php*. I have pointed the URL via `routes.php`, but it shows a failure message:-

[image: Class not found]

Here's part of the associated code:-

```
Route::get('/taskdetails/{id}', function ($id) {
        return view('tasksdetails', [
        'tasksdetails' => TaskDetails::orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get()
        ]);
    });
```

So, I wonder what does that mean? Did I miss some of the crucial step? Do I need to create a related class, if so, where & how am I going to do it?

Comment: Add use `App\TaskDetails` to your routes.php assuming that's the namespace of your `TaskDetails` model

Comment: Holy shoot, it works! Damn, none of the guide state about this... Thanks man...

Comment: @Kaydarin it's php stuff not framework related (read about namespaces ..etc for more details)

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja alright... I'm still learning programming though, that's why I didn't know some of it.... Anyway, thank you for everything...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just do this,

```
Route::get('/taskdetails/{id}', function ($id) {
        return view('tasksdetails', [
        'tasksdetails' => App\TaskDetails::orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get()
        ]);
    });
```